# ¿Etiqueta aside dentro o fuera de la etiqueta main?

Tags: html, html5

Estoy ingresando en el mundo del desarrollo y me surgió una duda.

La etiqueta `<aside>`, ¿debe ir dentro de la etiqueta `<main>` o sería una etiqueta padre y no hija dentro de esta última?

Answer (score 0):

El primer paso siempre debe ser revisar la documentación.

Algo oficial y formal, como MDN. [Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside) verás cómo se usan las cosas.

Los ejemplos y la [especificación](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-aside-element) indican que `<aside>` debe usarse como parte de tu documento, dentro de alguna sección, artículo o el body mismo. Y pues, la etiqueta main no crea secciones nuevas (semánticamente hablando) en el documento, así que va a dar lo mismo hacer

```html
<body>
  <main></main>
  <aside><!-- related to the body --></aside>
</body>
```

```html
<body>
  <main><aside><!-- related to the body --></aside></main>
</body>
```

Lo que va a pasar es que el navegador, al pintar tu página, va a relacionar ese aside con el elemento *seccionante* más próximo en la jerarquía (al artículo, seccion o body).

Comment: Muchas gracias. Tenés razón, debería de haber empezado con la documentación.

Comment: @ChristianAlvarenga no hay lío, piensa que son otros desarrolladores tratando de hacer que entendamos cómo hicieron las cosas. Por eso es sano y justo leerlos, a ver qué fue lo que hicieron :)